# TYPO3: How to extend sys_file_collection?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I want to add additional Fields to the TYPO3 File Collection.
 
I tried it with [this Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html) and added my fields to the TCA and the DB.
This works fine as long as I'm only in the Backend. But in Fluid I can't access my news Fields.
The next step was that I tried to extend the model to have a getter and setter for my field, and set extbase to use my model Class. But TYPO3 ignores it.

StaticFileCollection.php

```
class StaticFileCollection extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Collection\StaticFileCollection
{
/**
 * Subheader
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $subheader = '';

/**
 * Returns the subheader
 *
 * @return string $subheader
 */
public function getSubheader()
{
    return $this->subheader;
}

/**
 * Sets the subheader
 *
 * @param string $subheader
 * @return void
 */
public function setSubheader($subheader)
{
    $this->subheader = $subheader;
}
}
```

setup.txt

```
config.tx_extbase {
objects {
    TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Collection\StaticFileCollection {
        className = MyNamespace\MyExtension\Domain\Model\StaticFileCollection
    }
}
}
```

What did I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup should look like:

```
config.tx_extbase{
    objects {
        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category.className = VENDOR\Extension\Domain\Model\Category
    }
    persistence.classes {
        VENDOR\Extension\Domain\Model\Category {
            mapping {
                tableName = sys_category
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this dose not work on StaticFileCollection. The ExtensionBuilder creats that TS, but it also says the following: 
_The configuration for table "sys_file_collection" is not compatible
with extbase. You have to configure it yourself if you want to map
to this table_